# Creating my own repository on debian based linux

Tags: debian, repository

I want to create my repository on my debian based machine!

so:

```
$ touch /etc/apt/myown.list
```

urls:

```
http://www.domain.ext/path/to/repository
```

smb:

```
smb://path/to/repository
```

ftp:

```
ftp://ftp.domain.ext/path/to/repository
```

Right? So how can I put `nfs` and `cd-rom`? Please give me a clear example.

And how can I say to my machine to read myown.list?

Comment: Please specify your distro in the question

Comment: I have seen here in Unix & Linux there are similar questions for Ubuntu and RH. The official guide for Debian is here https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository; I use local repos for my own compiled/asssembled/converted packages, for caching the official repos I do suggest as alternative  `apt-cacher-ng`. I have a few hundred machines, and the  apt cache saves me time and bandwidth

Answer (score 2):

Regarding creating a new repository: please see [HowToSetupADebianRepository](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository), it contains instructions and pointers. There are a number of different software packages that create and manage debian repos and they range in complexity and scalability from "I just want a place to host a single static package in a file" to "I operate the main debian.org repo".

As for adding the repository to clients:

`/etc/apt/myown.list` does not do anything. To add repositories, you need to either add lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or add files to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` whose names end in `.list` and add the lines there. See the [manpage for sources.list](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sources.list) for details.

Also, I don't think you can put "exotic" URLs like `smb:` (or for example `sftp:`) in there. Keep it to `http:` (and `ftp:` if you must).

Comment: I want to stop going to urls in my repo. I want to read packages from my usb flash or from my cdrom... how can I do that?

Comment: Did you read the manpage I referenced? Specifically the section URI SPECIFICATION?

Comment: I couldn't understand really

Comment: I am talking about debian and ubuntu not fedora or centOS

Comment: You can use any protocol for which an APT transport method is available. `apt-file search /usr/lib/apt/methods/` lists what you can get. That doesn't include Samba; if you want a repository on Samba, mount it.